# Html's "select multiple" in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't even know how to search this on the web.

In html we have this kind of structure, `select multiple`, and with a few buttons and some javascript it is possible to easily `add` and `remove` objects from the list, I want to create something similar in android, more examples of my idea below.

The html example, source of my inspiration:

```html
<!-- It is just an example, sorry for the table layout -->
<table>
<tr><td>
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="add" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="remove" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

More of the what I want to do:

- I know of the android layout, it will not be exactly like the html
  one, I just want something similar.
- The list could be like the gmail's e-mail view
- The buttons would be below or above, don't know yet.

OBS: I'm good at java and have just started to learn some android development by my own, so I don't know exactly what is possible to create and how.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, EditText multi-line, but it's ugly and I don't want it to be text like, opening the keyboard whenever it receives the focus.

Comment: share your layout files. And possibly the screenshot of what you wanted

Comment: @res did you find your solution?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no, I had to use spinner because of the due date, but It was not what I wanted, that was to show all the itens, in a table like view, with rows, kind of the gmail way of showing e-mails.

Answer (score 3):

Hello What ever i get from your Question this can be your solution

You are looking for dropdown Right? In android we have `Spinner`.You can use `Spinner` static as well dynamic for add or remove values in `Spinner`

```
<Spinner
 android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:entries="@array/cars_name"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

for its value you need to add Array in String.xml

just like

```
   <string-array name="cars_name">
      <item> Volvo </item>
      <item> Saab </item>
      <item> opel </item>
      <item> audi </item>
   </string-array>
```

**Key classes are the following:**

- Spinner
- SpinnerAdapter
- AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

For More you can get it from Android Official Document [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner)

Answer (score 3):

According to your query, I think [Checkboxes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox) will do the work of multiple selections for you.

Alternatively, if you do not want to show all the options to the user you can try 
[Auto animate layout updates](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout):
I will work like below.

[image]